# I'm getting Haskell "parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)" and I cannot see what's wrong

Tags: haskell

Here is the code where I'm actually having the problem:

```
-----Function to test the postcondition----------------------------------
testPost :: Name -> Int -> [a] -> [b] -> IO ()
testPost _ _ [] [] = putStrLn "Test finished correctly"
testPost f_name n (t:ts) (o:os) = if (not aux_bool) then
                                         do putStr ("Failed on function " ++ (nameBase f_name) ++ " with inputs ")
                                            print ts
                                            putStr " and output "
                                            print os
                                            putStrLn ""
                                  else do
                                  do testPost f_name n ts os
                                      where aux_bool = post f_name n t o
```

The compiler just complains about the first line:

```
C:\Users\pegartillo\Desktop\TFG\CaseGenerator\src\UUTReader.hs:205:1:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

I am using the template haskell library, that's why it appears Name data type.

Comment: Why do you have two `do`s in a row?

Comment: One should be part of the else clause while the second one is outside the else. Maybe Isn´t it?

Comment: No. An empty do block would itself be an error.

Comment: so what should it be?
    else do return ()

Comment: @PedroGarcíaCastillo Should `testPost f_name n ts os` be included in both cases, or only in the `else` path? If `else` should truly be empty, I would consider using `Control.Monad.when` instead of `if`.

Comment: It should be evaluated in both cases

Comment: This is not a [mcve].

Comment: @PedroGarcíaCastillo `else return ()` would work (`do return ()` is fine, but the `do` is unnecessary for only a single expression). Though I think you would then have an issue with the concept of "after" the `if...`. Outside a `do` block there's no concept of sequencing expressions, so you would have to put the `if-then-else` and the `testPost ...` inside an outer `do`.

Answer (score 1):

To get it to compile, at least:

```
import Control.Monad (when)

newtype Name = Name { nameBase::String}

post _ _ _ _ = True

-----Function to test the postcondition----------------------------------
testPost :: (Show a,Show b) => Name -> Int -> [a] -> [b] -> IO ()
testPost _ _ [] [] = putStrLn "Test finished correctly"
testPost f_name n (t:ts) (o:os) = do
  when (not aux_bool) $ do
    putStr ("Failed on function " ++ (nameBase f_name) ++ " with inputs ")
    print ts
    putStr " and output "
    print os
    putStrLn ""
  testPost f_name n ts os
  where
    aux_bool = post f_name n t o
```

The layout with `if-then-else` and `do` can get tricky. Personally, I try to avoid mixing them if I can. Something that could have helped is pulling out the bodies of each block into their own expressions to simplify things when trying to debug.

Comment: Thanks a lot I didnt knew when at all but it's really usefull as you say to avoiud mixing if's and do's.

Comment: `if` is not indentation sensitive, so a statement containing the phrase "the layout of `if`" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user2407038 I'll admit I don't know the rules precisely, but I've had to adjust the layout of `if-then-else` when used inside a `do` block.